# Remove illegal URL characters with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array filled with strings, a value can for example be "not updated for > days". I use the values in the array to create some url's and need to remove the /\<> and other illegal URL characters. How do I easiest do this?

I started with

```
var Name0 = title[0].substring(1).replace(" ", "%20").replace("/", "") + '.aspx';
var Name1 = title[1].substring(1).replace(" ", "%20").replace("/", "") + '.aspx';
and so on but can I do this in a better way?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you wish to keep the symbols in the URI, but encode them:

```
encodedURI = encodeURIComponent(crappyURI);
```

If you wish to build 'friendly' URIs such as those on blogs:

```
niceURI = crappyURI.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, '');
```

Comment: I just want to remove them, like with .replace("/", "") but was wondering if there's an easier way than to have a lot of .replace() on every item in an array like in my first example.

Comment: Just clump up all the symbols to kill in one: `.replace(/[bad symbols here]/g, '')`

Comment: Or, kill everything except a whitelist: `.replace([^good symbols here]/g, '')`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) function which will properly URL encode the value.

Comment: The only way to go. (unless the OP's desire is to actually remove the offending characters to build nice-looking URLs).

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:global_functions:encodeuricomponent)?

Example usage

```
var encoded = window.encodeURIComponent("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486625/remove-illegal-url-characters-with-javascript/3486631#3486631");

// encoded contains "http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F3486625%2Fremove-illegal-url-characters-with-javascript%2F3486631%233486631"
```